# Trick with valuations

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I'm in middle of reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2780.pdf) (in the appendix, near the end) which is using a trick that I can not follow. 
The argument follows as such:

The proof is for simplicity of a polynomial, with degree $d = 2^e$. The $e$ will appear later, the rest is just for context.

Let $\nu$ be a valuation on some number field $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ extending $\nu_2$ the $2$ valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$.

If $\nu(x),\nu(y) \ge 0$, then $\nu((x+y)-(x-y)) = \nu(2y) \ge 1$. 
So if $\nu(x-y) = 0,$ then $\nu(x+y) = 0$. Hence $\nu(x^2 - y^2) = 0$ and thus 
$\nu(x^{2^k} - y^{2^k}) = 0$ for any $k \ge 0$.

In particular, we have
$\nu(x^{2^e} - y^{2^e}) > 0 $ implies $\nu(x-y) > 0$.
There are no special properties which I have not mentioned above as far as I can see.

I've been working through those sentences to prove the claims, I've proved up to "in particular". Do we not need the $\nu(x),\nu(y)\ge 0$ assumption? (this is used later, but not checked)

Proofs of stuff I can do:

The first claim, assuming $\nu(x),\nu(y)\ge 0$, we have $\nu(2y)  = \nu(2) + \nu(y) \ge 1 + 0 = 1$.

If $\nu(x - y) = 0$, then $0 = \nu(x - y) \ge \min(\nu(x + y), \nu(2y))$. As the second term is greater than $0$, we have that $\nu(x + y) \le 0$.
And $(\nu(x+y) \ge \nu(x) + \nu(y) \ge 0$, giving the equality $\nu(x+y) = 0$
 So $\nu(x^2 - y^2) = \nu(x+y) + \nu(x-y) = 0$.

Assume that for some $k \ge 1$,  we have that $\nu(x^{2^k} - y^{2^k}) = 0$. Then $0 = \nu(x^{2^k} + y^{2^k} - 2y^{2^k}) \ge \min(\nu(x^{2^k} + y^{2^k}), \nu(2y^{2^k}))$. The second term is greater than $0$ due to the factor of $2$, we have that $\nu(x^{2^k} + y^{2^k}) = 0$ with similar reasons to above, and so $\nu((x^{2^k} + y^{2^k})(x^{2^k} - y^{2^k})) = 0 = \nu(x^{2^{k+1}} - y^{2^{k+1}})$. By induction we have that $\nu(x^{2^k} - y^{2^k}) = 0$ for all $k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $x = \frac{3}{2}$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$. Then,

$$ \nu(x-y) = v(1) = 0 $$
$$ \nu(x^2 - y^2) = v(2) = 1$$

so $\nu(x^2 - y^2) > 0$, on its own, is insufficient to deduce  $\nu(x-y) > 0$.

---

In your own work, the hypothesis that $\nu(y) \geq 0$ was presumably invoked in order to conclude $\nu(2y) > 0$.

Comment: Would you mind if I changed the question to explaining the whole argument in the paper, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: @mdave16: New question would be more appropriate.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213919) sorry about taking so long to type it up.